# RegExp: find "cleverness" in a string

Tags: regex, regex-group, knime

My RegExpression:

```
((^|\s)(clever)($|\s))
```

It finds "clever" in the string:

- clever or not
- yahoo clever

but it doesn't find "clever" in this string:

- what means cleverness

I don't want to bother you with the three other RegExp variations of my line above but I tried different approaches already but can't make it work.

I am filtering terms in a table to cluster them into defined groups. I am looking for the adjective "clever". I dont want to find strings where clever is part of another word, in example "MacLever" or "alcleveracio".

Comment: Do you mean like `((^|\s)(clever(ness)?)($|\s))`

Comment: Please give some more examples of input and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
((^|\s)(clever))
```

Your regex contains `($|\s)` will force **clever** to be before a space or at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `^(.*\W)?(clever)(\W.*)?$`instead. \W matches any non-word character, so this will enforce that any string before "clever" include a nonword character at the end (and vice versa for the end.

You can plug it into https://regex101.com/ to see how it is working and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the word boundary `\b`.

```
\bclever\w*\b
```

or maybe better (no capitals allowed)

```
\bclever[a-z]*\b
```

If "clever" should be either at the beginning or at the end:

```
\b([a-zA-Z]+)?clever(?(1)|[a-z]*)\b
```

1. `\b` beginig of the string
2. `([a-zA-Z]+)` at least one character
3. `?` match even group is empty
4. `clever` matches the characters
5. `(?(1)` starts a condition, depends on group 1
6. `|[a-z]*)` if group matches, there doesn't may be any chars, else ( `|` ) there may be any lower case chars ( `[a-z]*` )
7. `\b` the final word boundary

Test and visualizing: [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/iCg6ycaWLZ5VUnb-)
[Infos about If-Then-Else](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)

---

[image: Regex image 1]

[image: Regex image 2]

(visulized by [Regulex](https://jex.im/regulex/))

Test it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/)